# Misleading wording on moderator tools privilege page

Tags: bug, status-completed

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools:

> Before voting to delete, please check that there are **no good answers**; if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

This wording seems strange/incorrect. I originally read the "if so" as meaning "if there are no good answers", which makes no sense with the rest of the paragraph. Instead, I believe "if so" should be replaced with "if there are":

> Before voting to delete, please check that there are **no good answers**; if there are, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!

Comment: How about "please check if there are any good answers; if there are..."? It's unambiguous and more positive.

Comment: Your example is more clear, but its the double negative that is confusing.  @AndrewMorton's example doesnt seem less straight forward. ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Or more smoothly, "please check for good answers; if there are any…".

Comment: @Andrew. That should be *weather*, not *if*.

Comment: @TRiG What has the weather got to do with it?

Comment: Gah. Gah and damn and blast and poop.

Comment: @TRiG Its 'whether' not 'weather'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I chose to use the wording "please check whether there are **any good answers**"; it seems to have addressed everybody's suggestions as thoroughly as possible.